# implement gcm on Ruby on Rails 5 server using GCM gem

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-cloud-messaging

Im developing an app that needs to have notifications when we have any updates. The server is on **Ruby on Rails 5** and im using https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm.

Is there anyone that can help me how to implement the server-side of gcm on **Rails 5**

`gcm = GCM.new("im putting my api key")
 registration_ids = ['tokens','tokens']
 options = {data: {message: '123'},
 response = gcm.send(registration_ids, options)`

When i try to make a push notification from GCM its stoping the Android App (Patato app has stopped).

If you guys have any idea implementing another GEM!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the server-side code, that looks fine (assuming api key and tokens are correct).

There's a bug in your android app, but I can't help with that since you didn't post your relevant android code.